# Stopping Fragment caching on a single page - Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, spree, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using Spree in my application and it's working pretty well except one issue that has got me thinking . On the product page , i have made products available according to the time of the day . But some of the products take values from the cache and based on time selected it puts in products that aren't supposed to be there . How can i stop caching on this single page of spree (I want it to be working on other pages though) .I have created an action for that page and put a before filter for it but it deletes cache from all the pages . Any inputs on the same would be highly welcome .

Comment: There is a railscast on it - http://railscasts.com/episodes/90-fragment-caching

Comment: Thanks , i have seen it already . But i was wondering , how to apply it on spree as it generates caching from the system itself on the server :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to replace the view and remove the cache block:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v3.0.0/frontend/app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb#L3

There are other solutions for disabling caching site wide, but nothing else that I know of for disabling specific caches that aren't terrible hacks.